# Method is not returning the correct value passed from observable subscription

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I'm trying to validate from an API (Angular's in-memory API) that a user exists given a username. The function `checkUsernameExists(username)` returns an `Observable<boolean>` based on whether the API returns undefined or a user object. I'm having an issue that regardless of the username (existing or not existing) it always returns false. I know that `getUser()` functions correctly as it returns undefined when a user doesn't exists and the user object when it does.

Preferably would only like to adjust the `checkUsernameExists` function if possible. This function is used for a (working) async validator. I've looked up all over how to solve this type of thing but can't find anything that isn't deprecated or fits what I need in order for it work properly.

```
  usersUrl = '/api/users';

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  users = this.http.get<User[]>(this.usersUrl).pipe(shareReplay());

  // gets a user object when subscribed to
  getUser(username: string): Observable<User | undefined> {
    return this.users.pipe(
      take(1),
      map((users: User[]) => {
        return users.find((user) => user.username === username);
      })
    );
  }

  // check if user exists
  checkUsernameExists(username: string): Observable<boolean> {
    var userValid = false;

    this.getUser('dummyuser@dummy.dum')
      .pipe(take(1)).subscribe(
        result => {
          if (result === undefined) {
            console.log('result: ', result);
            return (userValid = false);
          } else {
            console.log('result: ', result);
            return (userValid = true);
          }
        }
      );

    console.log(userValid)  // no matter the username, the value is always the same as its initialization (false)

    return of(userValid);
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your order of operations is the the problem in `checkUserNameExists` method

you must wait for the observable to complete. but your code is making call to an observable `this.getUser` and then immediately returning `return of(userValid)`.

since the observable has not completed, the vale of userValid is stil the default `false`. which is the behavior you described

Update your method to

```
checkUsernameExists(username: string): Observable<boolean> {
    return this.getUser('dummyuser@dummy.dum').pipe(
      .map( (result: any) => {
        if (result === undefined) {
          console.log('result: ', result);
          return (userValid = false);
        } else {
          console.log('result: ', result);
          return (userValid = true);
        }
     })
  );
```

}

this ensures that the `userValid` is only  returned when the observable has completed.

and is also removes the need for double susbscription

Answer (score 0):

/* How about you use promise */

```
checkUsernameExists(username: string): Promise<any> {
        return new Promise<any>((resolve, reject) => {
          this.getUser('dummyuser@dummy.dum')
            .subscribe(
              async (result: any) => {
                if(result) 
                {            
                  console.log('result: ', result);
                    resolve(result)         
                }
                else if(result && result.IsError)  
                {
                  console.log('result: ', result);
                  reject(result.Error)  
                }
            },
            (err) => {
              reject(err)   
            });        
        });
      }
```

/* To Call this Method => Do what you want to do with the result */

```
 await checkUsernameExists("Your_Username").then((res) => {
    console.log(res)
    }, (err) => {
    console.log(err)
    })
```